# Writing words back in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, data-structures

I have to read a sentence, and preserving the order of them,to write the words back, for example: input "I want a donut", output "I tnaw a tunod".

I wrote the code but it but it marks a bug in the **for** loop, honestly I don't know why.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce your sentence");
        String line;
        line = read.nextLine();

        int T = line.length();
        int Wspace = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
            if(Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)))
                x = Wspace++;

        for(int i = 0,int l = 0; i < T, l < x-1; i++, l++) //marks bugs here :({
            if  (!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i))) 
                arrl[i] = arr[i];
            else
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: bug in the for loop]

Comment: there is a little mistake in my code above :O , it should be linel[i]=line[i]; instead of arrl[i] = arr[i];

Comment: Where have you defined arrl and arr ? looks like the definition of these 2 variables is missing.

Comment: @RishiGoel read my first  comment

Comment: @RishiGoel however I'm having trouble defining linel[i]

Comment: Because I want that the 'l' of linel[i] to change, i.e. line0[i], line1[i], line2[i],... @RishiGoel

Comment: You need to work the algorithm. I can provide the answer but I don't think that is the best way to go ahead. Try using char arr[] = line.toCharArray(); this will give you an array to work with. You can write this in same array or you can write this in a new array.

Comment: @RishiGoel I already worked with the algorithm, that's how my code came from

Comment: @RishiGoel I added these lines: char arr[] = line.toCharArray();
    char arrl[] = null; and for(int p=0;p<T;p++)
        System.out.println(arrl[p]); (to print). But the output it's wrong

Comment: You need to reverse the words. Could you write your algorithm in words and see where you are reversing the word? I can see the problem in the logic, but as I said, I would prefer you work on it. The first part is separating the words, you have done that part ( using whitespace logic) . Second part is reversing the word, that needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your for loop.
1. Defining of `int i =0, int l =0;`

This should be written as `int i =0, l = 0;`
When defining in same line, the second int is not needed.

2. Conditions should not be comma(,) or semicolon(;) separated. We can use the && operator to join both the conditions together. so

   i < T, l < x-1;

should either be

```
i < T && (l < x-1);
```

Or some other way should be found to represent the condition. Rewriting the loop could be one such way as defined in the other answer.

Comment: problem fixed :), but a new one appeared, also there is a little mistake In my code, should be linel[i]=line[i]; instead of arrl[i] = arr[i];. The new problem is that I don't know how to declare the array linel[] where 'l' has to change, i.e. line0[], line1[], line2[],... What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply use the for sentence with twoo variables:
     for(int i = 0,int l = 0; i < T, l < x-1; i++, l++

did you try while sentence?

```
int i = 0, l=0;
            while(i<T && l<x-1) {
```

you have to create memory allocation for your array with new keyword

```
String arrl[] = new String[T];

import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author cesargarcia
 */
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce your sentence");
        String line;
        line = read.nextLine();

        int T = line.length();
        int Wspace = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i))) {
                x = Wspace++;
            }
        }

        String arrl[] = new String[T];

        String arr[] = new String[T];
        int i = 0, l=0;
        while(i<T && l<x-1) {
                 {
                     if (!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i))) {
                         arrl[i] = arr[i];
                     } else {
                         i++;
                     }

                 }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: there is a mistake in my code, it should be linel[i]=line[i]; instead of arrl[i] = arr[i];